# why isn't my original variable changed when I pass by reference a CoreData managed Object variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, pass-by-reference

why isn't my original variable changed when I pass by reference a CoreData managed Object variable?

So I have in my iPhone application, a coredata managed object called Config.  One of the variables in the XCode 4 produced *.h and *.m files is "@dynamic height;"  (I point this out because I wonder if it's related to this).  When accessing this variable in code it is an NSNumber.

So when I setup a new data selection view/controller I set a variable in this controller to be equal to height, so that when I change it in the next view & come back, it should be changed in the 1st view (pass by ref concept).

Only problem is that it doesn't seem to change the value?

Some code extracts:

```
@interface Config : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * height;
@end


@implementation Config
@dynamic height;
@end
```

Calling the 2nd view

```
// Prepare
SelectorController *sc = [[SelectorController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
sc.returnValue = self.config.height;

// Show New Window
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sc animated:YES];
[sc release];
```

Section Controller

```
@interface SelectorController : UITableViewController {
    NSNumber *_returnValue;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *returnValue;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSNumber` is immutable, that is, you can't change its value after it's created. When you assign a new value to an `NSNumber` property, it's a completely different object and the original object doesn't change at all.

Comment: oh ok - any suggestions in terms of what object type I could use to pass by reference between controllers, so that if the 2nd controller modifies it, the 1st controller can inherit the changes via the pass-by-reference effect?  (I was planning to have the 2nd controller be used for different selection tasks, so wanted to pass it the data and return variable - i.e. to get some reuse)

Comment: You should pass your entire `NSManagedObject` and let the 2nd controller modify its properties directly.

Comment: ok - but because I want to "reuse" the 2nd controller I'd have to do something like pass a string representation of the managed object attribute perhaps, so I could get/set the managed object attribute I want to work on in the 2nd controller using the key/value objective-c feature...anything better than this come to mind?

Comment: If your second view controller is only editing individual attributes, rather than the whole object, yes, passing the object and a key(path), using `setValue:forKey(Path):` could work well.